# I am getting a parse error with eval with }

Tags: bash

Here is my simple Bash script:

```
curljson() {
        eval "curl $* | python -m json.tool"
}
```

It simply outputs JSON a readable way.

But when I do:

```
curljson -X PUT -d '{"settings": {"number_of_shards": 3, "number_of_replicas": 1}}' http://192.168.1.111:9200/blogs
```

I get this error:

```
(eval):1: parse error near `}'
```

But when I do it strait in curl it works so it's seems to be my script.

So how can I make this Bash script accept `}`?

Comment: Don't use `eval` here. You don't need it and it is a *huge* security problem. Using `$*` is also "wrong" here. You should use `curl "$@" | python -m json.tool` instead (and make sure to pass arguments individually as you do in your example).

Comment: If you add `set -x` to the top of the function and `set +x` to the bottom you might be better able to see where the parse error is coming from. (Your usage of `$*` and `eval` combine to cause the problem. Though even using `"$@"` here would be a problem with `eval`. You are over-evaluating the line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `eval` here at all.

```
curljson() {
    curl "$@" | python -m json.tool
}
```

All `curljson` really does is pass all of *its* arguments as-is to `curl`, then pipe the output to a Python script. `"$@"` expands to the same sequence of words that the function received as arguments.